# Asp.net Request.Browser.Crawler - Dynamic Crawler List?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-crawler

I learned Why Request.Browser.Crawler is Always False in C# (http://www.digcode.com/default.aspx?page=ed51cde3-d979-4daf-afae-fa6192562ea9&article=bc3a7a4f-f53e-4f88-8e9c-c9337f6c05a0).

Does anyone uses some method to dynamically update the Crawler's list, so Request.Browser.Crawler will be really useful?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've been happy the the results supplied by [Ocean's Browsercaps](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/). It supports crawlers that Microsoft's config files has not bothered detecting. It will even parse out what version of the crawler is on your site, not that I really need that level of detail.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out Ocean's - I've been stuck with a very old set of BrowserCaps on our 1.1 sites for some time now.

Answer (score 6):

You could check (regex) against `Request.UserAgent`.

Peter Bromberg wrote a nice article about writing an [ASP.NET Request Logger and Crawler Killer](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a988f8c3-f69e-4ad2-a2e9-f9e01867769c/aspnet-request-logger-an.aspx) in ASP.NET.

Here is the method he uses in his `Logger` class:

```
public static bool IsCrawler(HttpRequest request)
{
   // set next line to "bool isCrawler = false; to use this to deny certain bots
   bool isCrawler = request.Browser.Crawler;
   // Microsoft doesn't properly detect several crawlers
   if (!isCrawler)
   {
       // put any additional known crawlers in the Regex below
       // you can also use this list to deny certain bots instead, if desired:
       // just set bool isCrawler = false; for first line in method 
       // and only have the ones you want to deny in the following Regex list
       Regex regEx = new Regex("Slurp|slurp|ask|Ask|Teoma|teoma");
       isCrawler = regEx.Match(request.UserAgent).Success;
   }
   return isCrawler;
}
```

Comment: Warning - this is *not* fool-proof! If you install certain versions of the Ask.com toolbar (in IE, at least) it will modify the user-agent to include 'Ask' in some form, causing false-positives.