# Would a browser ever ignore case sensitivity of the location header when responding to a redirect?

Tags: asp.net, browser, redirect

If a browser requests `http://site.com/?q=abc`

and gets a `301` redirect response to location `http://site.com/?q=ABC` (note case of querystring)

Is it possible for the browser to ignore the difference in case and re-request `http://site.com/?q=abc`, thus causing an infinite redirect loop?

That's the scenario that appears to be happening according to the IIS logs. It seems to be isolated to **Internet Explorer** with some variation of the **Ask toolbar** installed (based on user-agent values). I even installed the Ask toolbar, but have not been able to recreate this scenario in any way.

I can't post the source code, but for those that want something, here's the general logic:

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var q = Request.QueryString["q"];

    if (q == "ABC")
    {
        //render page as usual
    }
    else
    {
        Response.RedirectPermanent("[thispage]?q=ABC");
    }
}
```

As you can see, if this page is requested with `?q=abc` it will be redirected once, but then it'll render as usual because the redirect goes to `?q=ABC`.

Is there any scenario where the browser (specifically IE with the Ask toolbar) could ignore the case of the redirect location, causing an endless loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but this is probably the best way to close the loop. The excessive redirects was actually **not** caused by the code I posted. I was fooled.

We had an HttpModule that, ironically, used code mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431765/asp-net-request-browser-crawler-dynamic-crawler-list/431820#431820). It turns out that installing certain versions of the Ask.com toolbar on IE will modify the user-agent string to include 'Ask', causing false-positives on this 'IsCrawler' checker.

Because 'IsCrawler' evaluated to true in these cases, a different code path was executed that caused the infinite redirect loop. The querystring case changing was a result of this, not the web browser ignoring the location header as I was asking about.

Since I didn't even really answer *my question*, if anyone can post a somewhat authoritative answer on whether there are any known browsers or scenarios behaving as I asked about, I will mark that as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Ask toolbar is injecting itself into the request/response cycle that IE is using.  I've never developed a toolbar, but I'm betting it's pretty standard, as toolbars used to hijack URL input all the time.  If it then does some internal analysis before actually redirecting, I could see some sloppily written code doing case-insensitive comparison.

I'm hoping you've identified the obvious workarounds, such as forwarding to `?qq=ABC` and having your destination page use either `q` or `qq`.

Comment: Yes, the code definitely should be improved, but that's easier said than done. I'm just trying to verify the that I've correctly identified the cause of the problem. Thanks!