# Identifying web crawlers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-crawler

Is the following property reliable enough to identify search engine web crawlers?

[`Request.Browser.Crawler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpcapabilitiesbase.crawler.aspx)

My site creates a new user as a guest upon page request if they havent been to the site before and im getting more hits than my analytic's are suggesting. - alot more.

I use the snippet above to only create legit user guest accounts but im thinking some crawlers are getting through.

Perhaps I could use the HttpRequest UserAgent property to identify them. If so can someone please suggest a list of current crawler names, I believe the bing bot for instance is call bingbot as mentioned [here](http://onlinehelp.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/hh204496.aspx).

```
Request.UserAgent
```

**UPDATE:**

I know for sure that they are not being identified using Request.Browser.Crawler because a request coming from 65.52.110.143 is a serial offender, which I believe is a bingbot.

Comment: This may be of interest to you: [Asp.net Request.Browser.Crawler - Dynamic Crawler List?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431765/asp-net-request-browser-crawler-dynamic-crawler-list)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [Detecting 'stealth' web-crawlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233192/detecting-stealth-web-crawlers) There's no accepted answer, but there's alot of great ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Request.Browser.Crawler is sadly out-of-date

You could add detection of other user-agents as bots, manually.
Use the [**Browser Element**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228122.aspx) and not [browserCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk9az15a.aspx) as it is deprecated as of .NET 2.0

Example:

```
<browsers>
    <browser id="Googlebot" parentID="Mozilla">
        <identification>
            <userAgent match="^Googlebot(\-Image)?/(?'version'(?'major'\d+)(?'minor'\.\d+)).*" />
        </identification>
        <capabilities>
            <capability name="crawler" value="true" />
        </capabilities>
    </browser>
    .
    .
    .
</browsers>
```

This must be saved with a .browser extension under the `App_Browsers` directory in your application.

**[(List of Regexes to Match)](http://support.stormhosts.net/showthread.php?t=739)**

Comment: as im not familiar with this schema can you provide an example? im guessing it would look something upon the lines of:   <identification>
   <userAgent match="googlebot|msnbot|bingbot" />
   <capability name="crawler" value="true" />
</identification>

Comment: also is this schema only configurable to the machine config? As I believe adding to the web.config deprecated at the same time. NB. Im deploying to azure so this could be problematic.

Comment: Web.config was for the browsercaps, which is deprecated. This can be saved in the `app_browsers` with a .browsers extension. See updated answer. You can use [this file](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/CodeProject.xml) for  reference

Comment: If you want this for every website, you can add a *.browser file - the same format as the example above.

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers

You can use parentID="Default" and avoid any Mozilla specific settings.

Once you create the file, you will need to run aspnet_regbrowsers.exe /i

This will compile a DLL and register it into your GAC - now all websites on this machine will have identical crawler recognition.  And, I would guess your site would spin up faster too.

Downside is this will cause all your application pools to reset.